# Comparing powers with different bases without logarithms

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I want to compare :

$17^{31}$ and $31^{17}$ , this is a solution

[image]

but I want another one and without using logarithms, only using the fact that

$17=16+1=(2^4)+1$ and $31=(2^5)-1$

how could it be done ?

Comment: Do you care for another way which will not use neither logarithms nor the fact that you impose ?

Comment: please man go ahead

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}17 &= 2^4 +1\\
&> 2^4 \end{align}$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}17^{31} & > (2^4)^{31}\\
& = 2^{124} \end{align}$$

Meanwhile,
$$\begin{align}31 &= 2^5 -1\\
&< 2^5 \end{align}$$
and so,
$$\begin{align}31^{17} &< (2^5)^{17}\\
&= 2^{85} \end{align}$$

In sum, $17^{31} > 2^{124} > 2^{85} > 31^{17}$.